# Problems with Twig and PHP

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to create a content management system using Twig and PHP, but when I open the page, it says that there are no entries when there are. I have verified this using a `var_dump()`.

Code for the route:

```
$app->get('/articles', function() use ($app) {

    $approved_articles = $db_bsa->query("
        SELECT id, label, slug
        FROM approved_articles
    ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($approved_articles);

    $app->render('main/articles.php');

})->name('articles');
```

Code for the view:

```
{% extends 'templates/default.php' %}

{% block title %}Articles{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <article class="article">
        <header>
            <h2>Articles</h2>
        </header>

        <footer>
            <p class="post-info">A Directory Style Listing of our Active Articles</p>
        </footer>

        {% if approved_articles %}
            <ul>
        {% for approved_article in approved_articles %}
            <li>{{ approved_article.label }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>No articles at the moment...</p>
        {% endif %}

    </article>

{% endblock %}
```

Also, a longer chain with more background info is posted here:                                            https://www.codecourse.com/forum/topics/problems-using-twig-and-php/329

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `approved_articles` to twig when you render the template.

```
$app->render('main/articles.php', array('approved_articles' => $approved_articles));
```

Twig doesn't automatically find variables in your controller. You need to explicitly pass template variables like `approved_articles` into the Twig rendering engine.

As a side note, your `articles.php` template file is named with a `.php` extension, but it is not actually a PHP file. Usually templates are named with a `.twig` extension.

Comment: Do you know how to pass variables in to twig? Also, do you know how to pass definitions, like `INC_ROOT` to twig. Thanks!

Comment: You can pass anything you want into the array. For example, to pass INC_ROOT, do something like `array('approved_articles' => $approved_articles, 'root' => INC_ROOT)`. You can then reference it in your template with the name `root`. Also see the twig [constant function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/constant.html).